# Are cheap 2.5" external hard disks constrained to Exfat and incompatible with Time Machine? Is this a physical limitation / hardware issue?

Tags: time-machine, external-disk, hfs+, sata, exfat

I bought two 2TB 2.5" external HDDs that came with the following warning message in a Readme file contained in the drives.

*"The drive can only be formatted with Exfat and cannot be formatted in other for mats, suchas NTFS, FAT32, FAT. Otherwise it will cause the hard drive t be unusable!
This hard disk is only suitable for windows system and XP system not suitable for PS4, xbox macbook,tv, etc.
The disk needs to be inserted into the USB interface of the device's motherboard. If the transfer method is used, there may be insufficient power supply to the disk."*

Both drives appeared to work straight out of the box. However, I got errors when trying to partition them (I use a MBP, mid-2015 Retina, MacOS 10.3.3). Now one of the external drives has become unusable. So...I'm guessing this could be because these are cheap no-brand drives which I ordered from China, similar to these:

- [https://www.amazon.com/Womdee-External-Drive-Portable-Compact/dp/B0832PLGLZ?th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0832PLGLZ)
- https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/223984609481
- https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/373049736464

And I'm guessing the manufacturer has assembled them or configured them in this way (limited to Exfat) in order to cut costs. My questions are:

1. Why/how an external drive can be manufactured to be permanently only Exfat?
2. Is this a hardware constraint or physical limitation imposed by the manufacturer or by the USB to SATA bridge used?
3. Is there a way to overcome this so that I can use them for Time Machine backups?...Has anyone been succesful in backing up with Time Machine on these types of 2.5" external hard drives?

**Attempts at finding answers:**

My investigation so far has brought me to this:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/150702/182479 (which hints that it could be related to the controller of the external case)

From the Terminal query below, it appears that the drive is a JMicron device. I've now got in touch with JMicron and waiting to hear back (will post updates here). In the meantime, if anyone can shed any light and answer/respond to any of the above questions I'd very much appreciate it.

`diskutil info /dev/disk1`:

```
   Device Identifier:        disk1
   Device Node:              /dev/disk1
   Part of Whole:            disk1
   Device / Media Name:      JMicron Generic Media

   Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)

   Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)

   File System:              None

   Content (IOContent):      FDisk_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 USB
   SMART Status:             Not Supported

   Total Size:               2.0 TB (2000398934016 Bytes) (exactly 3907029168 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        Not applicable (no file system)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)
   Ejectable:                Yes

   Whole:                    Yes
   Internal:                 No
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported
```

Below is a screenshot showing the readme file and the warning contained in it.

[image]

NB. Question asked earlier to try and restore the unusable drive here [Unusable 2.5" external HDD. Partition failed with the error -69760: Unable to write to the last block of the device. Exfat only? Repairable?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/391754/unusable-2-5-external-hdd-partition-failed-with-the-error-69760-unable-to-wr)).

Comment: I think all the errors in the readme file says it all. Bite the bullet, eat the loss, and get some quality hardware. Especially if you're using it for backups!

Comment: Had I read this file in an online description before buying I would've thought twice about ordering. Having said that, I'm curious to learn more about these type of disks.

Comment: It depends on which of those 3 you bought from & if you are actually UK. 1st ad, US, don't know. 2nd ad, send back as "unfit for purpose" Look up UK "distance selling regulations" They pay postege, both ways, you get total refund. 3rd ad, you were warned. You can still return within 14 days of receipt, but YOU pay return postage. [Look up those regs & make sure you KNOW them in future]. Sellers will try to blame you.

Comment: @Tetsujin it was the second one which is now unlisted. I posted the other ones as examples (third one by searching the readme in Google). Yes I'll most probably return (I think for eBay, shouldn't need to pay return postage if mis-sold). I was posting this questions because I'm genuinly curious about these types of drives and if it was a software/hardware constraint.

Comment: mhm. I can't answer your question as it stands, sorry, I just don't know…. but that 2nd ad you're clean. PayPal will be on your side too [you never lose money with PayPal]. UK law backs you up on the 'mis-sold' too, so the vendor hasn't a leg to stand on. You get a total refund inc all postage] & they get a black mark on their account. Read https://www.gov.uk/online-and-distance-selling-for-businesses There's a pdf too somewhere on there to keep for future ref. Learn it ;-)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help Tetsujin! I always seem to find you and @Klanomath around in SE. I'm keeping this question open so I can update it if I hear back from JMicron or from anyone else who can shed some light. So far it seems these Chinese manufacturers have been able to make and sell a very cheap yet large external hard disk with the exception that it only works with Exfat. It's like they've created a new product. That's partly why I'm curious to know more.

Comment: If the limitation is due to the enclosure controller, not the controller on the HHD, then one option might be removing the HDD and putting in in a new and better external enclosure.

Comment: I have several WD My Book 4 TB Ext HDDs. On one, the USB Port got messed up so it didn't work. When I took the HDD out of the case and tried using it in an ext enclosure, I found out that how it was formatted was dependent on the WD case's controller, not the controller on the HHD. I needed to recover the data, so I had to buy another and temporarily swap out the HDD. Once finished I took the HDD and put it in a new and different ext enclosure, reformatted it and it works just fine. I eventually need more storage so having the extra WD drive worked out. (But I don't buy WD My Book anymore!)

Comment: @user3439894, Thank you for this input! Removing the current enclosure doesn't appear straightforward. Nevertheless, can you recommend an enclosure that guarantees allowing to partition to HFS+ format and therefore compatible with Time Machine? I'm assuming all enclosures would come with a controller? Any particular brands or models?

Comment: Had a quick look at enclosures and they don't seem expensive. If it was about cutting costs, surely the manufacturer could've easily used an enclosure with a controller that supports HFS+? https://www.amazon.co.uk/2-5-Inch-Tool-free-External-Enclosure-Black-USB-3-0/dp/B079FR7H5H/

Comment: This is the one I'm currently using for 2.5.' SATA HDDs [ORICO 2.5 inch USB3.0 External Hard Drive Enclosure (2577U3)](https://www.orico.me/product/orico-2-5-inch-usb3-0-external-hard-drive-enclosure-2577u3/). I also use the same brand and model for 3.5" HDDs [ORICO 3.5 inch SATA3.0 USB3.0 External HDD Enclosure](https://www.orico.me/product/orico-3-5-inch-sata3-0-usb3-0-external-hdd-enclosure/). I've purchased them from my local Computer Store, here in the US. They have quite a few to choose from on their web site. I've had no issues with them.

Comment: As to any guarantees, without knowing the manufacture make and model of the HDD itself, no I can't give any guarantees. I also probably wouldn't give any guarantees anyway!  I just know if you can't return them, what do you have to loose?

Comment: @user3439894 understood. You're correct, and I agree about the guarantees! :)

 Thank you for the suggestions and the links! Will take a look and see if I can remove this case. Many thanks again!